# Google_Service_Exception error code : 401

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-extensions

I have integrated my web application with google login. When i am running in core php everything works fine but it's not working in yii framework with same codes. I got the following error while i am running,

```
Google_Service_Exception

{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "authError",
"message": "Invalid Credentials",
"locationType": "header",
"location": "Authorization"
}
],
"code": 401,
"message": "Invalid Credentials"
}
}
```

Controller

```
require_once Yii::app()->basePath . '/extensions/GoogleAPI/vendor/autoload.php';
public function actionIndex()
    {
        // echo Yii::app()->request->basePath; exit;


        $gClient = new Google_Client();
        $gClient->setClientId(".....");
        $gClient->setClientSecret(".....");
        $gClient->setApplicationName("Omega");
        $gClient->setRedirectUri("http://localhost/project/index.php/site/GoogleLogin");
        $gClient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
        $loginURL = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
        $this->render('index',array('loginURL'=>$loginURL));
    }
    //Redirecting function
    public function actionGoogleLogin()
    {
        $googleClient= new Google_Client();
        $oAuth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($googleClient);
        $userData = $oAuth->userinfo_v2_me->get();
        print_r($userData); exit;
    }
```

View page

```
<a href="#" class="btn-google m-b-0" onclick="window.location = '<?php echo $loginURL ?>';">
            <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
            Google
          </a>
```

Comment: the error says it all **Invalid Credentials**

Comment: so what solution